# How can I create a shorter alias URL to a longer URL using an .htaccess file?

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting

Using an *.htaccess* file, I want to make one specific URL have a shorter alias like this:

**Original URL:**

```
mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=2:rss1klik&format=feed&Itemid=160
```

**Alias to the original URL:**

```
mydomain.com/index.php/rss/rss1klik
```

Note that both URLs should display the same content.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304492/htaccess-redirect-without-changing-address-bar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following would work:

```
RewriteRule ^/index\.php/rss/rss1klik$ /index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=2:rss1klik&format=feed&Itemid=160 [L]
```

But this may look better:

```
RewriteRule ^/rss/rss1klik$ /index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=2:rss1klik&format=feed&Itemid=160 [L]
```

Then the URL would be `http://mydomain.com/rss/rss1klik` which is shorter/cleaner still.