# Set Alias path using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, php, apache, url-rewriting, magento

I have a path like this

```
http://host.ip/nl/producten-en-diensten/abonnementen-met-gsm
```

which will retrieve the correct content and I also want to receive the same content when I access the below URL also

```
http://host.ip/nl/business/producten-en-diensten/abonnementen-met-gsm
```

Note:

- `host.ip/nl/` - Static
- `producten-en-diensten/abonnementen-met-gsm` - Dynamic, it will change
- `/business` keyword will append next to `nl`

I have referred to the rule given in this post: [How can I create a shorter alias URL to a longer URL using an .htaccess file?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67283/how-can-i-create-a-shorter-alias-url-to-a-longer-url-using-an-htaccess-file)

but no success

@Magento URL rewrite management will do exactly this, but I am trying to achieve this using `.htaccess`.

I have tried like this but it is redirecting

```
RewriteRule (^|.*?/)nl/business/(.*)$ /$1nl/$2 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Here is my rewrite tag in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## Enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

## Business Rewrite
    RewriteRule (^|.*?/)nl/business/(.*)$ /$1nl/$2 [NC]

############################################
## You can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## Workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## Never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## Rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `R=302,` from your rule.   `R` means "redirect" and `302` means "temporary type":

```
RewriteRule (^|.*?/)nl/business/(.*)$ /$1nl/$2 [L,NC]
```

For further info about your rule:

- `L` means "last" (don't apply further rewrite rules)
- `NC` means "no case" (case insensitive so `/NL/BUSINESS` will also match -- this may not be what you want)

Comment: In the example URLs give, it looks like `$1` will always be empty, so this could be simplified further.

Comment: i am getting 404 when I use this rule

Comment: My guess is that you have other rewrite rules for Magento.   You probably need to put this rule first and remove the `L` so that the Magento rewrite rules also work.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller i have updated the question with the htaccess rule,still it is returning 404

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have tried this rule also 
`RewriteRule ^host.ip/nl/business/(.*) /$1` not working but i checked the rewrite rule in this website  http://htaccess.mwl.be/ it is showing correctly

Comment: You should never need to put the host name in a rewrite rule.   You may have to rewrite it to `index.php` to have Magento handle it.   I'm not very familiar with Magento, however, so I can't give you much specific advice about that.

Comment: @prasanna "i checked the rewrite rule ... it is showing correctly" - you must have tried a different URL/rule. That rule couldn't possibly work with the URL stated in your question and neither does it "match" at `htaccess.mwl.be`.

Comment: This may not be possible without an external redirect. It depends how Magento is able to route the URLs. From the `.htaccess` file above, all requests are ultimately sent to `index.php` - for Magento to process and route the request. Most front controllers then examine `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the requested URL. If you internally rewrite the original request, the `REQUEST_URI` superglobal still holds the URL of the original request - the URL that the user sees in the address bar ie. the URL with the `/business` path segment. If this doesn't exist as a URL in Magento then you get a 404.

Comment: Thanks for the response @w3dk, Is there any alternate way to achieve this in magento without using .htaccess,by overriding the url rewrite class in magento something like that.

Comment: Well, you mention that the "Magento URL rewrite management will do exactly this"? I imagine you probably could "override the url rewrite class" or write a plugin or something, but this is now a more involved programming exercise. I don't know enough about Magento unfortunately to know what would be involved.